# When I run a java swing app via xwindow over ssh session, is it's classpath my local box or that of the ssh server?

Tags: cygwin, ssh-tunnel, x-windows, remote-connection

When running java sandbox apps over a cygwin (Moba terminal) ssh xwindows session, is it running on my local machine or is it executing on the server, with just the interface being displayed to my machine?

Because I'm not sure which environment variables it picks up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole program is running on the server. The only thing provided by your computer is the X11 (Xwindows) display.